# Trouble closing a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to stop my running thread. *ftprun.requestStop()* sets the value of the while loop so that the application stops.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        Thread ftpthread= null;
        LocalFTP ftprun = null;

        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "Start Sorter":
            if(ftp) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Sorter and ftp cannot run at the same time");
            } else {
                sorter=true;
                btn.setText("Stop Sorter");
                btn.setBackground(SystemColor.green);
            }
            break;
        case "Start ftp":
            if(sorter) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Sorter and ftp cannot run at the same time");
            } else {
                ftp=true;
                btn.setText("Stop ftp");
                btn.setBackground(SystemColor.green);
                Config config = new Config();
                try {
                    File cf= new File(Configfile.configfile);
                    if (cf.exists()) {
                        config=ConfigurationTools.openconfig(Configfile.configfile);
                    }
                    else {
                        ConfigurationTools.writeconfig(Configfile.configfile, config);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                ftprun= new LocalFTP(config,config.getlocalftpinterval());

                ftpthread=new Thread (ftprun);

                ftpthread.start();

            }
            break;
        case "Start Uploader":
            uploader=true;
            btn.setText("Stop Uploader");
            btn.setBackground(SystemColor.green);
            break;  
        case "Stop Sorter":
            sorter=false;
            btn.setText("Start Sorter");
            btn.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
            break;
        case "Stop ftp":
            ftp=false;
            btn.setText("Start ftp");
            btn.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
            ftprun.requestStop();
            break;
        case "Stop Uploader":
            uploader=false;
            btn.setText("Start Uploader");
            btn.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
            break;  

        }
    }
```

Any suggestions. I tried to set the Thread and runnable variables to static but I just got an error.

Comment: It would help if you'd say where you're getting the exception. It would also really help if you'd come up with a short but complete example which *only* demonstrated the problem.

Comment: Like I said, I'm getting the null pointer exception when try to stop the thread which is done with ftprun.requestStop(). I will mention that in the question.

Comment: All the stack trace tells me is that ftprun is null when I try stopping the thread and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
LocalFTP ftprun = null;

switch(...) {
    case ...:
        ...
        ftprun = new LocalFTP(...); 
        ...
        break;
    case ...:
        ...
        ftprun.requestStop();
        ...
        break;   
}
```

This is a *local* variable. It's only being set to a non-null value in a different case block, so there's no way it can be non-null in the situation where you're calling `requestStop`. It will only happen in a different invocation of your `actionPerformed` method, with a separate local variable (which will be null).

It sounds like this is really part of the state of the overall object - so you should make it an instance field within your object, rather than a local variable.

Comment: So you are saying I need to move the variables out of the actionPerformed() and initiate them as part of the object. Thanks that works.

Comment: @Codeguy007: Good. Do you understand *why* it works though? It's important to understand that "the currently executing operation" is logically part of the state of the object - and state needs to be stored in fields rather than instance variables.

Answer (score 4):

`ftprun` is a local variable of the `actionPerformed()` method. So it's initialized when you start a thread, and then goes out of scope.

Once the stop button is clicked, the actionPerformed() method is called once again, and its `ftprun` local variable is reinitialized to null. This variable should be an instance field, not a local variable.